# Place cursors at both ends of a selection in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'd like to create a key binding in Sublime Text 2 to place cursors at both ends of the selected text. For instance, if I bound this command to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then selecting a word, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, and pressing <kbd>space</kbd> would add a space on both sides of the word.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

I realize the answer as soon as I posted this: Just use a snippet which multiple instances of the cursor (represented by `$1`) around the selection:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "$1${0:$SELECTION}$1"}, "context":
  [
    { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": true }
  ]
}
```